# How to create a search Action in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I am using Alfresco Enterprise 6.2. Similar to the live search, I am creating a search Action for folders that I have in document library.

I have updated the custom-actions.js as follows:

```
onActionSearch: function dla_onActionSearch(record){
        window.open(Alfresco.constants.PAGECONTEXT +'dp/ws/faceted-search?', "_self");       
}
```

I have also added folder scope in `faceted-search.get.js` as below. I have hardcoded the value `folder1` just to test if it works:

```
  scopeOptions.push({
  id: "FCTSRCH_SET_FOLDER_SCOPE",
  name: "alfresco/menus/AlfCheckableMenuItem",
  config: {
    label: "folder",
    value: "folder1",
    group: "SEARCHLIST_SCOPE",
    publishTopic: "ALF_SEARCHLIST_SCOPE_SELECTION",
    checked: false,
    hashName: "scope",
    publishPayload: {
     label: "folder",
     value: "folder1"
    }
  }
});
```

However it dos not consider the folder scope when performing the search. Instead, it consider 'folder1' as a site. How can I correctly perform a search within folder scope?

Answer (score 2):

Please check below widget,It is considering scope as a siteId always.

https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/AlfSearchList.js_.html

Comment: Is extending AlfSearchList just enough or do I have to extend SearchService.js as well? Also, can I please know what's the best way to extend them?

Comment: You need to override SearchService.js and need to add logic of folder.